# omniauth facebook doesn't show image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, authorization, omniauth

I am using the omniauth-facebook gem and it all works perfectly, except the profile picture won't show; instead of showing the picture when I put in the code `image_tag current_user.image.to_s` or `image_tag current_user.image` it shows text (saying Picture?type=normal, square, large) instead of the picture itself.

omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :developer unless Rails.env.production?
provider :facebook, '166053726877178', 'df9249e9b70ef047e7a9456c7ebf9632',
:image_size => 'square'
end
```

and user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :image, :name, :nickname, :provider, :uid
  has_many :pictures

def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
    user.nickname = user.email.split("@").first
    user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
  end
end

acts_as_voter
end
```

thing is, with this type of code it worked on a previous app, but it won't work here.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

to get the image of user use these code instead
for each kind of facebook profile image

```
def largeimage
"http://graph.facebook.com/#{self.uid}/picture?type=large"
end
 def normalimage
"http://graph.facebook.com/#{self.uid}/picture?type=normal"
end
```

def smallimage
   "http://graph.facebook.com/#{self.uid}/picture?type=small"
   end

in your views

```
 <%= image_tag(current_user.largeimage)%>
```

and so on